# how to make a gallery wherein the images used are from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, image-gallery

i just wanna ask on how to make a simple gallery for my website wherein the images used to display are from database and will automatically display on the gallery? so that when i have to update the images i won't enormously create thumbnails..??

Comment: it's bad idea. images will not be cached ("expired" headers), to fetch each image you will run php/apache process, instead of lightweight nginx. And content of images should be escaped before inserting into table..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend against keeping the image data in a database, it's almost always a bad idea.

I would recommend storing metadata about the images in the database and then including a pointer to the file (the image's path on the local filesystem). If you need to make thumbnails create them as the images are added, store them on the filesystem too and store the path to them in the table too.

Another approach is to have the filename of the image and thumbnail as a function of the image ID. E.g. store it on the server at `/some/directory/images/123.jpg` and `/some/directory/images/123_thumbnail.jpg` where `123` is the id of the image.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql BLOB storage - Example: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_%28blob_storage%29.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can create the thumbnails and update the database when the images are uploaded to a directory within your http path.  A simple php routine can extract the picture names from the db and include them in your gallery.